# Change a gridview's datasource dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two `DataTable`'s which I want to use as `DataSoure` for a `GridView`. And when an user clicks on a `button1` I need to load the first table and the user clicks `button2` the second table should be loaded. My current problem is that the tables don't have the same structure (one has more columns) and when the user clicks `button1` first and after clicks `button2` the second table is loaded with the right values but it shows the extra columns from `table1` as well.

What's the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: If it is __WinForms__ it will be a __DataGridView__ not a __GridView__ which is a different Control from __WPF__. Please be precise with theses things or you'll wrong anwers! If the results of `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` are good enough you're done. If not you'll have to code what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually adding columns set the property [`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true. This will cause the grid to create columns according to the data source.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on the Habib answer:

```
private void LoadTables()
{
    // Mock the tables data
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    // Clear data from gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = null;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    // Load first table
    GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    // Clear data from gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = null;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    // Load second table
    GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```